# multiple JOIN on SQL – bigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am working on  simple bigQuery that returns me font-sizes across github. Everything works until I add the next `JOIN` statement. I am looking for a file where my regex matches, then getting its repo name and path. Then I though that it would be nice to have date of the last commit as well and when it was created. Though these data are in different dataset and I can't help myself with this logic.

```
SELECT
  f.repo_name, f.path, c.font_size, com.committer
FROM
 [bigquery-public-data:github_repos.sample_files] f
JOIN (
  SELECT
    id,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(content, r'(font-size.*?;)') AS font_size
  FROM
    [bigquery-public-data:github_repos.sample_contents]
  WHERE
    REGEXP_MATCH(content, r'(font-size.*?;)')
) c
ON
  f.id = c.id
JOIN(
  SELECT
    committer,
    repo_name
  FROM
     [bigquery-public-data:github_repos.sample_commits] 
) com
ON 
  f.repo_name = com.repo_name
```

With this code I get an Error `Only leaf fields can be selected. Field committer used in the query is non leaf.`

Comment: Please use [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) instead. Does that fix the problem? You'll need to use backticks instead of brackets with the table names.

Comment: Yes, that did the trick, thanks!

Comment: Consider posting the working query as an answer to your question in case it helps future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use standard SQL!

```
#standardSQL

SELECT f.repo_name, f.path, 
       REGEXP_EXTRACT(c.content, r'(font-size.*?;)') as font_size,
       com.committer
FROM `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.sample_files` f JOIN
     `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.sample_contents` c
     ON f.id = c.id JOIN
     `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.sample_commits` com
     ON f.repo_name = com.repo_name
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(content, r'(font-size.*?;)');
```

Notes:

- The table referencing is a little different in Standard SQL.
- The equivalent to `regexp_match()` is `regexp_contains()`.
- The subqueries are unnecessary.